# How to rewrite this theme call to drupal_render

Tags: theming

I have this call to the [theme function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme/7) in my code :

```
print theme('image_style', 
            array( 
                'path' => $news_image['uri'],
                'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
                'alt' => $news_image['alt'],
                'title' => $news_image['title'],)
            );
```

However in the theme function documentation you can read :

> Avoid calling this function directly. It is preferable to replace
>   direct calls to the theme() function with calls to drupal_render() by
>   passing a render array with a #theme key to drupal_render(), which in
>   turn calls theme().

So, how do I rewrite the above simple function using [drupal_render](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_render/7) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this...

```
$build = array(
  '#theme' => 'image_style',
  '#path' => $news_image['uri'],
  '#style_name' => 'thumbnail',
  '#alt' => $news_image['alt'],
  '#title' => $news_image['title'],
);

$rendered = drupal_render($build);
```

Where every named variable you would normally pass to the `theme()` function as the second parameter becomes a #-prefixed key in the render array.