# From theme() to drupal_render()

Tags: theming

I'm a Drupal themer, learning how to develop for Drupal. Currently I'm reading a book called **Drupal 7 Module Development** in which the following code is used.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
*/
function first_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ($delta == 'list_modules') {
    $list = module_list();

    $theme_args = array(
        'items' => $list,
        'type' => 'ol'
    );
    $content = theme('item_list', $theme_args);

    $block = array(
        'subject' => t('Enabled Modules'),
        'content' => $content,
    );

    return $block;
  }
}
```

Its a simple module that returns a ordered list of all the enabled modules. Notice they are using the `theme()` function.

As a themer, I wanted to know more about this function, so I looked it up on [drupal.org](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84096/how-to-rewrite-this-theme-call-to-drupal-render), and saw this:

> Avoid calling this function directly. It is preferable to replace direct calls to the theme() function with calls to drupal_render() by passing a render array with a #theme key to drupal_render(), which in turn calls theme().

So I tried replacing it with `drupal_render()`, and came up with this:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_block_view().
 */
function first_block_view($delta = '') {
  if ($delta == 'list_modules') {
    $list = module_list();

    $theme_args = array(
        '#theme' => 'theme_args',
        'items' => $list,
        'type' => 'ol'
    );
    $content = drupal_render($theme_args);

    $block = array(
        'subject' => t('Enabled Modules'),
        'content' => $content,
    );

    return $block;
  }
}
```

This however, is giving an error: `Theme hook theme_args not found.`
Am I missing something? I would appreciate any help, and if possible, an explanation of what I did wrong. (since I'm learning this stuff.)

I've seen a similar question posted here, and followed its instruction, but no success.
[How to rewrite this theme call to drupal_render](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/84096/how-to-rewrite-this-theme-call-to-drupal-render)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a typo.

Just replace

```
'#theme' => 'theme_args',
```

with

```
'#theme' => 'item_list',
```

There is no theme called "theme_args".

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is no longer giving an error, and rendering my block, however, with no content. The block shows up in the correct region with the title, but its empty. Any reason why `item_list` works better? Is it a default function that Drupal recognises?

Comment: Well, Drupal provides lots of pre-built theme functions or called as theme HOOKs. You can have a look at https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_item_list/7. Also in https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal just by writing "theme_" in the search box will give you most of the themes shipped with default Drupal installer profile.

Comment: Aha, thanks for the links, it clears up quite alot. Small question on the side: As a Drupal developer, should you learn/memorize all those functions? So you know what is possible, and what is not. I've also figuered out why my block was empty, I forgot to add `#` in front of `items` and `type`.

Comment: As you progress with Drupal development over the years you would remember the functions, hooks and APIs. :)